# Strongly typed urls in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to URLs from the LinkBuilder in Microsoft.Web.Mvc. AT the moment, I have:

LinkBuilder.BuildUrlFromExpression(???, RouteTable.Routes,
        x => x.Index())

But I'm not sure how to get the request context in all cases. E.g. If I'm in a IHttpModule, is it possible for me to somehow get the request context so I can create a URL like this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [System.Web.Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.aspx) for your MVC setup, you can implement an [IRouteHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.iroutehandler.aspx) ([example](http://fredrik.nsquared2.com/ViewPost.aspx?PostID=466)) which will return a new instance of your custom [IHttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx) class. Since the logic for instantiating the HttpHandler goes inside the [GetHttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.iroutehandler.gethttphandler.aspx) method of the IRouteHandler, and the IRouteHandler has access to the [route request context data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.requestcontext.aspx), you can pass that in to your HttpHandler's constructor and use it appropriately.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but I don't see how this helps when trying to create a URL with LinkBuilder in say an HttpModule or even a traditional code behind.

Comment: @Nick the LinkBuilder uses the RequestContext from System.Web.Routing. You must be using routing to get that RequestContext. I explained how to create an HttpHandler that can be used in a routing context.